# Problem of RUN shell script in Dockerfile in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, docker

I'm trying to use Docker with my `macOS Catalina v10.15.4`

When I tried to `RUN ./test.sh` in Dockerfile and there is some error occured.

This is my Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN mkdir -p /home/rootfs/src
COPY test.sh /home/rootfs
WORKDIR /home/rootfs
RUN chmod +x test.sh && ./test.sh
```

When I tried to build this, it did not find the script as below:

```sh
$ docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  264.6MB
Step 1/5 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
 ---> 4e5021d210f6
Step 2/5 : RUN mkdir -p /home/rootfs/src
 ---> Running in d0813632475d
Removing intermediate container d0813632475d
 ---> 87a6e284993d
Step 3/5 : COPY test.sh /home/rootfs
 ---> 26d281d0002c
Step 4/5 : WORKDIR /home/rootfs
 ---> Running in 4c7e81a514a7
Removing intermediate container 4c7e81a514a7
 ---> dab2872eb15a
Step 5/5 : RUN chmod +x test.sh && ./test.sh
 ---> Running in a03f3e5d29b4
/bin/sh: 1: ./test.sh: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x test.sh && ./test.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I check the info of test.sh `file test.sh` in macOS.

Got this:

```sh
test.sh: POSIX shell script text executable, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Comment: Works for me. What does `file test.sh` say?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I run `file test.sh` in macOS. Got this: `test.sh: POSIX shell script text executable, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `test.sh` script contains Windows line endings as specified in output of `file test.sh`.  Convert them to Unix line endings:

```
$ dos2unix  test.sh
dos2unix: converting file test.sh to Unix format...
```